# How to work with FadeIn() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm making a navigation bar, when the user clicks on menu tab that specific image changes it's working fine. but i want the image to be fadeIn() when it changes.

[image]

[image]

my jQuery

```
 $('#menu-cross').on('click',function(){
   var changeImage  = "images/navigation-icons/closemenu.png";
        $(this).attr('src', changeImage); 
 });
```

i was tryin

```
 $('#menu-cross').on('click',function(){
    var changeImage  = "images/navigation-icons/closemenu.png";
    $('#menu-cross').fadeIn(500 , function(){
      $(this).attr('src', changeImage); 
    });
 });
```

my Html

```
 <img src="images/navigation-icons/menu.png" id="menu-cross">
```

Comment: Hey Danial - when you ask a question on stack such as the one above. Try to provide your example code via [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/) This makes debugging far easier and your question is more likely to be answered, thanks.

Comment: @danialpervaiz: you are changing `src` of an element, don't think this technique can easily enable us to produce a `fade` effect. instead, I recommend you to have two `img` elements, one with `menu.png` and other with `closemenu.png`. fading them between one another then should become relatively easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing right except you need to `fadeOut` before `fadein` and change the src in `fadeOut` like one below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/owht3fyL/)**

```
var changeImage  = "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/geomicons/32/672366-x-128.png";
var originaImage = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lightly-icons/30/652841-menu-120.png";
$('#menu-cross').on('click',function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){
      if($(this).attr('data-changed')=='true')
      {
          $(this).attr('src', originaImage).attr('data-changed','false');    
      }
      else
      {
           $(this).attr('src', changeImage).attr('data-changed','true');       
      }
    }).fadeIn(500);
 });
```

But I'd prefer this beauty solution **[here](http://sarasoueidan.com/demos/navicon-transformicons/)** from this **[blog](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/navicon-transformicons/)**

Comment: Any time!! Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

your image is also shown, so fade In effect wont be work. so you can hide it and show again

```
 $('#menu-cross').on('click',function(){
    var changeImage  = "images/navigation-icons/closemenu.png";
    $(this).attr('src', changeImage); 
    $('#menu-cross').fadeOut(0).fadeIn(500);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fade in like :

```
 $(this).attr('src', changeImage).fadeIn('slow');
```